# Dynamically adding columns to a tablerow. Adding textviews in a loop. settext not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I  have a table layout with 9 rows. first one is for the heading. but the no of columns vary. so i need to add textview dynamically to the table row. 
Iam inflating the table row and adding the text for the first column which is fixed. other coulmns iam trying to add it in a loop. but iam getting only the first cell.

my expected out put is like this:

```
col#   A   B   C   D  E  F
----------------------------
1      65  6   6   5  6  7
----------------------------
2      6  4   7   4  6  8
```

no of columns can be 3 to 6. but row is 8

i get a out put like this:

```
 col#   
    ----------------------------
    1   
    ----------------------------
    2
```

iam trying to display the first row. but iam getting only the first cell. can anybody help?

my xml with a table row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
        <TextView android:id="@+id/sn4"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    style="@style/normalText"
                    android:textColor="@color/title"
             />



</TableRow>
```

i have another xml for a textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <TextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:id="@+id/txtfactor"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                style="@style/normalText"
                android:textColor="@color/title"
         />
```

in my code:

tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tbltrail);
        for(int i=0; i<=noOfTrials ; i++){
            TableRow child = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trial_table, null);
            child.setId(i);
            TextView sno = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.sn4);
            if(i == 0){
                sno.setText("Col#");

```
            for(int j=0; j<count; j++){
                FactorObj factorObj = factorList.get(i);
                View row = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trial_row_content, null);
                TextView factorname = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtfactor);
                factorname.setId(200+j);
                Log.v(null, "factor name "+factorObj.getFactorName());
                factorname.setText("sdf");
                child.addView(row);



            }
            tbl.addView(child);


        }else{
            sno.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            for(int j=0; j<count; j++){
                FactorObj factorObj = factorList.get(i);
                View row = (View) 

                getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trial_row_content, null);
                TextView factorname = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtfactor);
                factorname.setId(100+j);
                factorname.setText("ss");
                child.addView(row);


            }
            tbl.addView(child);
        }

    }
```

Comment: addView reparents a view? 'row' is never used. Instead part of it is added to a container. IMO not clean.

Comment: sorry i have edited the code. in each table row i have kept a textview as fixed to fill in the serial no. other textviews are generated dynamically from a layout and added to this table layout. i don't know whether iam doing it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

For this Create a view group of rows

```
mCell = new CellViewGroup(this,parameters);
```

and
Refer the table layout from xml

```
 mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytable);
```

create table row dynamically

```
TableRow mRow = new TableRow(this);
```

add the view group to the row

```
mRow.addView(mCell);
```

add it to the table layout

```
mTableLayout.addView(mRow);
```

if you dont know about viewgroup just google it.....

Comment: i have tried this for a different app. here iam trying to inflate the tablerow from a xml. when displaying in the loop. the setText is not working. anyway thanks.